# How do I iterate over the contents of a folder within the current working directory in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

New to Swift.

Having checked that a folder called `data` exists within the current working directory using this code:

```
// Get the current working directory
let fileManager = FileManager()
let cwd = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var isDir: ObjCBool = false

if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: cwd + "/data", isDirectory: &isDir)){
    if (isDir.boolValue) {
        // There is a directory called `data`
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to iterate through the contents of the `data` folder. Specifically, I'm just trying to store the names of all top-level folders within the `data` folder. I've looked at the `FileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` function but I think that takes a `URL` not a `String` and I don't know how to convert my path (`cwd`) to a `URL`.

The `fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath:)` function does take a `String` but I don't think it returns an iteratable result.

Can anybody help?

Comment: try URL(string: cwd )

Comment: Have you checked the return type of `contentsOfDirectory(atPath:)` ? It returns `[String]`, you can iterate on it.